# Adding a border around an image of arbitrary size, including responsiveness [html/css/js]

Tags: html, css, image

I know there are a lot of questions of a similar nature but none see to get to this specific use case that I can find (including youtube and googling) - apologies if this is a trivial question and appreciate the help in advance.

I'm trying to get a responsive image working with a fixed border around it. Namely, the image will fill the container it's in, up to its max length or width, maintaining the aspect ratio, but the container will be of arbitrary dimensions as it will be scaled depending on the viewport/screen. So, imagine a square image in a rectangle that changes between vertically tall to horizontally wide, scaling the image until it hits either border.

Every solution I've tried pretty much makes the 'container' for the image get the background, which means in one direction, it looks fine, but when stretched to the alternate, it stretches out.

[Behaviour via screen-snips of two browser windows side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFzRj.jpg)

Things I've tried:

1. Creating a div container and setting the background colour. Doesn't work as I can't (or am ignorant to how) to force it to fit the aspect ratio of the photo and not just fill the parent container.
2. Targeting the img attribute directly under the parent class using bg-clour and padding/margin. This basically behaves as #1.
3. Adding a drop shadow targeting the img attribute with no fade or offsets, white colour. Behaves just like 1.
4. Tried using a border targeting the image - doesn't seem to be implemented for image targeting.
5. Trying to figure out a way to scale it with a background image instead - similar issues to 1 in constraining the container size to the image aspect ratio.

2-4: (combined, obviously commented out when trying each individual one):

```
.photo_parent img{
  /* border: 1em solid white; */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px white;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: white;
}
```

It's possible the issue is actually how I'm implementing the scaling restrictions. Here's the code I'm using that seems to be working:

```
.photo{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

This obviously solves one direction but gives my the undesired behaviour in the other. I could of course flip the height/width auto portion but just gives the 'dual' of the problem. Also, using only contain won't work as I want the image to maximally take up container space. Object-fit fill doesn't meet the goal as it messes with aspect ratio. Object-fit cover will crop the image. At least I've learned that the way HTML/CSS process images is to consider they're within their own object... (assuming that's even correct).

Is there something I'm missing with my lack of experience with CSS?

What I almost want is a CSS child selector which maps the container dimensions to the child (img) aspect ratio. I'm hoping I don't have to go into JS to do this but so be it if that's the case.

Anyway, thanks for any tips. If it matters, I'm trying to implement this in a 'slide' using swiper.js.

Comment: You can use background size cover in the css!

Comment: ok so I guess you already know how to keep the aspect ratio of a box either with a width or hight already given. If you know those emthods, then you can use media queries to apply either of those method depending if the screen is in landscape or portait.

Comment: @tacoshy - the problem is that the images are of arbitrary size/aspect ratio. If they're all square, that would work but I don't think the media queries will otherwise work outside of known aspects. (TBH, they're not completely arbitrary but I will have at the minimum portrait and landscape ratios so... same problem I'd think?)

Comment: @AlePlo - cool, another tool to play around with - I'll look into if I can get it to work that way. I did see another Q&A suggest that background image are bit less ideal for SEO, though.

Comment: If you need to have them as img tags you maybe can find a workaround by wrapping the image in a container with overflow hidden but it will be harder to implement I think and the upside in SEO I wouldn't know if it's really worth it.

Comment: @AlePlo lol interesting hack. I'll see if I can make that path work somehow. I'm less optimistic immediately though because I think it still falls under the same problem - scaling the container size to an arbitrary image aspect ratio/size.

Comment: I don't know if it is arbitrary, you always need the picture to be at least 100% on the larger side of the container, then the shorter side will adapt accordingly. So you may be able to do this with media queries swapping min-width 100% height auto with min-height 100% and width auto. The thing with having them as backgrounds is that it lets you establish a origin position, very helpful when centering the image to show the more important parts.

Comment: Understable! Good luck!